# Reacting to user input

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm currently busy with a bot that searches an area around the user. The user has the ability to increase the search radius. This is the code I'm using to handle the users input, so far the "Yes" bit of the code works, however I'm not sure how to re-trigger the search.

The search is initially triggered by a luis intent so I thought that would probably be the easiest way to navigate to the different tasks in the bot. However I'm not sure how to send a message to the bot programmatically / trigger a luis intent from code.

```
[LuisIntent("Stores")]
        public async Task Stores(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
        {
            var reply = context.MakeMessage();
            reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
            reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
            List<CardImage> images = new List<CardImage>();

            InfoClass IC = new InfoClass();
            latitude = "-29.794618";
            longitude = "30.823497";
            LocationObject[] StoreLocations = IC.NearBy(latitude, longitude, Radius, context);
            int count = StoreLocations.Length;
            for (int z = 0; z < count; z++)
            {
                CardImage Ci = new CardImage("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=764x400&center=" + StoreLocations[z].Latitude + "," + StoreLocations[z].Longitude + "&zoom=15&markers=" + StoreLocations[z].Latitude + "," + StoreLocations[z].Longitude);
                images.Add(Ci);

                HeroCard hc = new HeroCard()
                {
                    Title = StoreLocations[z].StoreName,
                    Subtitle = StoreLocations[z].Subtitle,
                    Images = new List<CardImage> { images[z] },
                    Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
                };

                CardAction ca = new CardAction()
                {
                    Title = "Show Me",
                    Type = "openUrl",
                    Value = "https://www.google.co.za/maps/search/" + StoreLocations[z].Latitude + "," + StoreLocations[z].Longitude
                };
                hc.Buttons.Add(ca);
                reply.Attachments.Add(hc.ToAttachment());
            }
            await context.PostAsync(reply);
            PromptDialog.Confirm(context, promtDecision, "Would You Like To Change The Search Radius ?", attempts: 100);
        }
    async Task promtDecision(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> userInput)
    {
        string inputText = await userInput;
        if (inputText.Equals("yes") || inputText.Equals("y"))
        {
            RadiusPromt(context);
        }
        else
        {
            StartUp(context, null).Start();
        }
    }
    void RadiusPromt(IDialogContext context)
    {
        PromptDialog.Number(context, AfterPromptMethod, "Please Enter Search Radius (In Kilometers)", attempts: 100);
    }
    async Task AfterPromptMethod(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<long> userInput)
    {
        int Radius = Convert.ToInt32(await userInput);
        await context.PostAsync("Store Locations");
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the search part in a dedicated method and call this method from your Luis intent and when you need elsewhere.
BTW, why don't you use `PromptConfirm` for a Yes/No question?

Comment: The search is currently in it's own method, I thought I could trigger the luis method that calls that method with the 'await context.PostAsync("Store Locations");' however this picks up that it's being sent from the bot side so luis doesn't kick in. I'm checking up the 'PromtConfirm' thanks for the tip !

Comment: Add more code (at least the LuisIntent...). But in order to avoid doing bad things (like simulating a LuisResult, etc.) you should really use a dedicated method for the search and call it from both your LuisIntent method and in the other place you need

Comment: Added the intent code, I miss understood you, I'm currently moving it into its own private method however i'm getting a Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.InvalidNeedException: 'invalid need: expected Call, have Wait' on the promptDialog.Confirm. Could this be because it's in a void method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I understood from your problem, here is an implementation calling a method that I called `SearchInArea`, using an `int` parameter.

This method is called from 2 places:

- when your LuisIntent `Stores` is recognized
- when you come back avec changing the radius value

Code:

```
[LuisIntent("Stores")]
public async Task Stores(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    var defaultRadius = 10;
    await SearchInArea(context, defaultRadius);
}

private async Task SearchInArea(IDialogContext context, int radius)
{
    var reply = context.MakeMessage();
    reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
    reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
    List<CardImage> images = new List<CardImage>();

    InfoClass IC = new InfoClass();
    latitude = "-29.794618";
    longitude = "30.823497";
    LocationObject[] StoreLocations = IC.NearBy(latitude, longitude, radius, context);
    int count = StoreLocations.Length;
    for (int z = 0; z < count; z++)
    {
        CardImage Ci = new CardImage("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=764x400&center=" + StoreLocations[z].Latitude + "," + StoreLocations[z].Longitude + "&zoom=15&markers=" + StoreLocations[z].Latitude + "," + StoreLocations[z].Longitude);
        images.Add(Ci);

        HeroCard hc = new HeroCard()
        {
            Title = StoreLocations[z].StoreName,
            Subtitle = StoreLocations[z].Subtitle,
            Images = new List<CardImage> { images[z] },
            Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
        };

        CardAction ca = new CardAction()
        {
            Title = "Show Me",
            Type = "openUrl",
            Value = "https://www.google.co.za/maps/search/" + StoreLocations[z].Latitude + "," + StoreLocations[z].Longitude
        };
        hc.Buttons.Add(ca);
        reply.Attachments.Add(hc.ToAttachment());
    }

    await context.PostAsync(reply);
    PromptDialog.Confirm(context, PromptDecision, "Would You Like To Change The Search Radius ?", attempts: 100);
}

private async Task PromptDecision(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<bool> userInput)
{
    var userBoolChoice = await userInput;
    if (userBoolChoice)
    {
        RadiusPromt(context);
    }
    else
    {
        StartUp(context, null).Start();
    }
}

private void RadiusPromt(IDialogContext context)
{
    PromptDialog.Number(context, AfterPromptMethod, "Please Enter Search Radius (In Kilometers)", attempts: 100);
}

private async Task AfterPromptMethod(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<long> userInput)
{
    int radius = Convert.ToInt32(await userInput);
    await SearchInArea(context, radius);
}
```

Comment: Changing the methods from async voids to async Tasks like your answer did the trick, thank you !

Comment: I am getting "Sorry my bot code has an error" when it reaches the PromptDialog in the SearchInArea Task, this only happens on messenger. Does messenger support prompt dialogs ?

Comment: Yes Messenger supports Prompt Dialogs (and Prompt Confirm in those dialogs). I cannot test all the code as I do not have all the necessary code from your question (no StartUp, no InfoClass...).
Did you add ApplicationInsights to your project? You will be able to see your Exception with it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44927645/promtdialog-error-on-messenger-bot-c-sharp-bot-framework - I've opened up a new question with updated code and a description on what I've done so far.