# PromptDialog error occurs in Messenger bot

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I'm having an issue with a PromptDialog in my messenger bot, Whenever it reaches the prompt dialog it throws a "Bot Code has an Error". I've tried moving it around the code but it still throws it no matter where I put it, I've tried to place it into its own method and simply call the method and pass the context to it but again it didn't help.

I think it may be something in the LocationReceivedAsync however I'm not sure what.

```
[LuisIntent("Stores")]
public async Task Stores(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    await StoreSearch(context); 
}
private async Task StoreSearch(IDialogContext context)
{
    var reply = context.MakeMessage();
    reply.ChannelData = new FacebookMessage
    (
        text: "Please share your location with me.",
        quickReplies: new List<FacebookQuickReply>
        {
            new FacebookQuickReply(
                contentType: FacebookQuickReply.ContentTypes.Location,
                title: default(string),
                payload: default(string)
            )
        }
    );
    await context.PostAsync(reply);
    context.Wait(LocationReceivedAsync);
}
public virtual async Task LocationReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
{
    var reply = context.MakeMessage();
    reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
    reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
    List<CardImage> images = new List<CardImage>();

    InfoClass IC = new InfoClass();
    var msg = await argument;
    var location = msg.Entities?.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Type == "Place");
    if (location != null)
    {
        latitude = location.Properties["geo"]?["latitude"]?.ToString();
        longitude = location.Properties["geo"]?["longitude"]?.ToString();
        LocationObject[] StoreLocations = IC.NearBy(latitude, longitude, Radius, context);
        int count = StoreLocations.Length;
        for (int z = 0; z < count; z++)
        {
            CardImage Ci = new CardImage("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=764x400&center=" + StoreLocations[z].Latitude + "," + StoreLocations[z].Longitude + "&zoom=15&markers=" + StoreLocations[z].Latitude + "," + StoreLocations[z].Longitude);
            images.Add(Ci);

            HeroCard hc = new HeroCard()
            {
                Title = StoreLocations[z].StoreName,
                Subtitle = StoreLocations[z].Subtitle,
                Images = new List<CardImage> { images[z] },
                Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
            };

            CardAction ca = new CardAction()
            {
                Title = "Show Me",
                Type = "openUrl",
                Value = "https://www.google.co.za/maps/search/" + StoreLocations[z].Latitude + "," + StoreLocations[z].Longitude 
            };
            hc.Buttons.Add(ca);
            reply.Attachments.Add(hc.ToAttachment());
        }
        await context.PostAsync(reply);
        PromptDialog.Confirm(context, promtDecision, "Would You Like To Change The Search Radius ?", attempts: 100);
    }
    context.Done(location);
}
async Task promtDecision(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<bool> userInput)
{
    bool inputText = await userInput;
    if (inputText)
    {
        RadiusPromt(context);
    }
    else
    {
        await mainMenu(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: As told in the other topic, please give us the exception details and all the necessary code to try to replay on our side

Comment: The only exception I have is the one messenger throws, ApplicationInsights doesn't show me anything and dev.botframework throws There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError. The code here is all the relative code. The rest just holds location info and menus.

Comment: When trying to simulate your case, I got feedback on Insights: `invalid type: expected System.Boolean, have Entity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your implementation of `LocationReceivedAsync`: you should not put a `context.Done(location)` at the end of the method when you got a location. It should be on an `else` statement.

This `context.Done` is trying to complete the current dialog whereas you are still trying to do actions (in your case asking for a radius change).

Correction:

```
private async Task LocationReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
{
    var reply = context.MakeMessage();
    reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
    reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
    List<CardImage> images = new List<CardImage>();

    InfoClass IC = new InfoClass();
    var msg = await argument;
    var location = msg.Entities?.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Type == "Place");
    if (location != null)
    {
        latitude = location.Properties["geo"]?["latitude"]?.ToString();
        longitude = location.Properties["geo"]?["longitude"]?.ToString();
        LocationObject[] StoreLocations = IC.NearBy(latitude, longitude, Radius, context);
        int count = StoreLocations.Length;
        for (int z = 0; z < count; z++)
        {
            CardImage Ci = new CardImage("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=764x400&center=" + StoreLocations[z].Latitude + "," + StoreLocations[z].Longitude + "&zoom=15&markers=" + StoreLocations[z].Latitude + "," + StoreLocations[z].Longitude);
            images.Add(Ci);

            HeroCard hc = new HeroCard()
            {
                Title = StoreLocations[z].StoreName,
                Subtitle = StoreLocations[z].Subtitle,
                Images = new List<CardImage> { images[z] },
                Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
            };

            CardAction ca = new CardAction()
            {
                Title = "Show Me",
                Type = "openUrl",
                Value = "https://www.google.co.za/maps/search/" + StoreLocations[z].Latitude + "," + StoreLocations[z].Longitude
            };
            hc.Buttons.Add(ca);
            reply.Attachments.Add(hc.ToAttachment());
        }
        await context.PostAsync(reply);
        PromptDialog.Confirm(context, PromtDecision, "Would You Like To Change The Search Radius ?", attempts: 100);
    }
    // Change is here
    else
    {
        context.Done(location);
    }
}
```

Edit: one more point about your implementation. I don't understand why your "search and results display" code (around `LocationObject[] StoreLocations = IC.NearBy(latitude, longitude, Radius, context);`...) is in the callback from Facebook prompt (`LocationReceivedAsync`) if you want to reuse it after the RadiusPrompt (implementation not visible here but I guess it's what you would like to do no?).

Maybe you should keep `latitude` and `longitude` setup in this method, and then call a new method that can also be called from your RadiusPrompt